# PHP code to retrieve from database to HTML drop down list not working

Tags: php, mysql

My database contains list of countries with ccode and country name. This code works here except that the list of countries are not displayed in dropdown list. but when i blindly select a random selection from drop down list, it is inserted into db.

Country

Select Country

```
        <!-- PHP code to retreive drop down list from database countries -->

        <?php   

        include('connection.php');

        $sql = "SELECT country FROM countries ORDER BY ccode ASC";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

                {

                    echo '<option       value="'.$row['country'].'">'.'</option>';
                }

        ?>

     </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the value inside the `<option>` tag.

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['country'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute is for specifying the value which is sent with the form, usually an id. You have to add the country names between the tags to display them.

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['country'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
```

But when the two are the same you don't need to specify `value`:

```
echo '<option>'.$row['country'].'</option>';
```